# How do I figure out what my SAML error is being caused by?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am slowly building a .net core service provider web app using a SAML library called `itfoxtec-identity-saml2`

I have progressed to the point where I actually can connect to the IdP, but I am getting an error from the IdP that simple says, "Unable to Decode".

In my service provider web app project, when I step through it in Visual Studio, it gets to the `AuthController.cs` class and the error is thrown by the IdP when this is sent here:

```
    [Route("Login")]
    public IActionResult Login(string? returnUrl = null)
    {
        var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();
        binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { relayStateReturnUrl, returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/") } });

        return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(config)).ToActionResult();
    }
```

Is there any other way to help debug this?

Here is all the data I could gather from the browser:

Headers

```
GET https://singlesignon.lowell.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO?SAMLRequest=fJBBb4MwDIX%2FCso9JCRQIAKkar1U2tRqVDvsMqU0VZEgyWIj7ecvdDuslx3t589%2Bzw3oeRJebRe82VfzuRjA5GueLKgfpSVLsMppGEFZPRtQOKh%2B%2B%2FKsRMqVDw7d4Cbyl%2Fkf0QAm4OgsSfa7lnxIaaoqL6%2B0rHVN87LQtBZc0rOp8nNW8CyvNyR5MwEi05K4IoIAi9lbQG0xtriQlG%2BoqE6ZVEWheJWWMnsnyS6mGa1er7XkhuhBMeajA%2B8Cpn5ETM1lYePFs5jkOk6GrT4FOx76E%2Bv7A%2BmaeyR1vxi6Y0TWiSdnrRnQhYY96L%2Fl4z%2B7bwAAAP%2F%2FAwA%3D&RelayState=ReturnUrl%3D%252F HTTP/1.1
sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: https://localhost:7133/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: shib_idp_session=dcefe3bd1b8e866da71b733a98a96a49ccb9d15f1481a74ba447757dcf86a7cf; JSESSIONID=D9B5D82C717EF64AE5D4AED9446A1042

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1655
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 13:59:31 GMT
Connection: close
```

Payload

```
SAMLRequest: fJBBb4MwDIX/Cso9JCRQIAKkar1U2tRqVDvsMqU0VZEgyWIj7ecvdDuslx3t589+zw3oeRJebRe82VfzuRjA5GueLKgfpSVLsMppGEFZPRtQOKh++/KsRMqVDw7d4Cbyl/kf0QAm4OgsSfa7lnxIaaoqL6+0rHVN87LQtBZc0rOp8nNW8CyvNyR5MwEi05K4IoIAi9lbQG0xtriQlG+oqE6ZVEWheJWWMnsnyS6mGa1er7XkhuhBMeajA+8Cpn5ETM1lYePFs5jkOk6GrT4FOx76E+v7A+maeyR1vxi6Y0TWiSdnrRnQhYY96L/l4z+7bwAAAP//AwA=
RelayState: ReturnUrl=%2F
```

Chrome SAML Tracer:

```
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                     xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                     ID="_76e6448i-79a9-475a-9203-be84b1501496"
                     Version="2.0"
                     IssueInstant="2023-06-28T13:55:08.731Z"
                     Destination="https://singlesignon.lowell.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO"
                     >
    <saml2:Issuer>DevConnector</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>

GET
SAMLRequest: fJBBb4MwDIX/Cso9JCRQIAKkar1U2tRqVDvsMqU0VZEgyWIj7ecvdDuslx3t589+zw3oeRJebRe82VfzuRjA5GueLKgfpSVLsMppGEFZPRtQOKh++/KsRMqVDw7d4Cbyl/kf0QAm4OgsSfa7lnxIaaoqL6+0rHVN87LQtBZc0rOp8nNW8CyvNyR5MwEi05K4IoIAi9lbQG0xtriQlG+oqE6ZVEWheJWWMnsnyS6mGa1er7XkhuhBMeajA+8Cpn5ETM1lYePFs5jkOk6GrT4FOx76E+v7A+maeyR1vxi6Y0TWiSdnrRnQhYY96L/l4z+7bwAAAP//AwA=
RelayState: ReturnUrl=%2F
```

Comment: An AuthnRequest requires a `RelayState` to be passed to the IdP, and many IdPs expect to get it via `POST` instead of `GET` (since URLs are captured by all sorts of log systems and they don't want to run the risk of PII (like passing the `subject` in the AuthnRequest).

Comment: @AndrewK. Oh ok, I didn't know that, I believe the SAML library I am using, `itfoxtec-identity-saml2` uses `GET` for the Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IdP maybe expect you to use HTTP POST given the error message `Unable to Decode`.

The samples default use HTTP GET with the `Saml2RedirectBinding`, like this in the .NET core sample
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L30

You can change to use HTTP POST by changing the `Saml2RedirectBinding` to `Saml2PostBinding`.

Comment: Oh ok, so I just need to change that one thing and it should work?

Comment: Does your SAML library support Shibboleth ?

Comment: Yes just that one thing. If Shibboleth support SAML 2.0 is should work.